# "Unable to retrieve BIOS information"

Tags: windows-server-2008, dell, bios, dell-poweredge

While trying to update the BIOS' of PowerEdge 2950s to 2.6.5 from 2.2.6, I got this message, "Unable to retrieve BIOS information." These are remote servers so updating via boot-disk isn't feasible.

Anyone have any suggestions on how to accomplish BIOS updates?

Comment: Would enabling overclocking of the BIOS help at all?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to do a minor update first? 2.2.6 -> 2.3.*, etc (if it's possible).

Comment: yes, but those installers give me the same error.